# rsync backup remote server maintaining groups and owner

Tags: backup, rsync, remote, permissions

This might seem like a problem that should have been covered millions of times but I am running into issues that after days of scouring the net, I still can fix.

I have a remote server that I want to backup in its entirety. I am running rsync from a local machine with a user *seb* that has access to the server over ssh with a public rsa key. The remote has two users, *seb* and *git* each with its own folder. User *seb* is sudoer on the remote.

The command that I have been running from the localhost

```
sudo rsync -av --rsync-path="sudo /usr/bin/rsync" seb@remote:/ /path/to/backup/
```

This runs fine in terms of authentication and permissions. I have to run remotely as root with sudo, because otherwise I get a permission denied on stuff owned by *root* and *git*.

I run locally as *root* with sudo because `rsync` manual states that in order to preserve group and owner settings as is done with the `-a` flag, the receiving user should be *root*.

However after `rsync` is finished the group and owner for the *git* owned files are changed to `rtkit` and `bluetooth` respectively. Now I presume that it only fails for *git* user and not for *root* and *seb* since the latter two users exist on both machines.

Is there a way to keep the group and owner settings without creating the user *git* on the local machine?

p.s. for full disclosure, since I am not sure if it would matter, but I don't expect so, I am running `rsync` over a non standard port with `-e "ssh -p PORT"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely user 'git' and user 'rtkit' share the same UID(or GID) on both machines.  So the files are being saved with the correct UID/GID but that maps to different user names on each machine.  Check /etc/passwd and /etc/group on the 2 machines to see where the UID / name mappings overlap.

If this is just a backup, it really doesn't matter what the UID / GID mapping is, when you have to restore the backup to the original machine the mappings will be back to the names you use on machine 1.

To fix it, you would have to sync your users / groups between both machines.  Or switch to using centralized logins with LDAP or NIS or SMB.

Comment: To add to this, if this is just for making back ups use the `--numeric-ids` flag as well, to preserve the correct uid/gids.

Comment: I ran some tests and the UID/GID is maintained and mapped properly upon restoring the backup. Thanks for the answer